# how to create a Grails web application using Eclipse Indigo?

Tags: grails, eclipse-indigo

I want to create a web application in Grails.

I am new to the Grails framework, and I want to know the step by step procedure to create a web application in Grails using Indigo Eclipse

Comment: the answer did help you?

Answer (score 0):

See this http://grails.org/Eclipse+IDE+Integration and follow the documentation.
Heres another tool: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/groovygrails-tool-suite-ggts-eclipse-indigo-37#.UbnGsUC1HXI